# How to get length of complex datatype column in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table contains columns of type `array` and `map` and I want to filter record where array/map column contains more than **N** elements, how to do that?

**DDL:**

```
create table test (id string, v1 array<int>, v2 map<string,string>)
```

**Query:**

```
select * from test where length(v1)>10 or length(v2)>10
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * from test where size(v1)>10 or size(v2)>10
```

---

Demo

```
create table test (id string, v1 array<int>, v2 map<string,string>);
insert into test select 1,array(1,2,3,4,5),map('K1','V1','K2','V2','K3','V3');
```

---

```
select  size(v1),size(v2)
from    test
;
```

---

```
+----+----+
| c0 | c1 |
+----+----+
|  5 |  3 |
+----+----+
```